# Blazor /Pages folder required for all pages/views?

Tags: razor, blazor

Using the default Blazor helloworl app, i copied the FetchData.razor page to a separate, custom folder.

The result:

> The page is not being rendered properly (the page is taking up the
>   whole screen / the navigation menu is gone).

Question:

> Do blazor pages/views must be in the /Pages folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are free to put components in whatever folders you wish, the `Pages` folder is just what comes with the template. But you will notice in the default templates, the `Pages` folder has a file called `_Imports.razor` which contains the following:

```
@layout MainLayout
```

This means all components in the `Pages` folder automatically get the `MainLayout` applied. If you've moved your component to another folder you will need to either copy the above line to your component or copy the `_Imports.razor` into your new directory.